# Laravel file not showing from storage after php artisan storage:link

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-storage

I have run command `php artisan storage:link` and it's created storage file in public directory and called via `src="{{asset('storage/app/'.$slide->image_path)}}"` it's showing in src http://peg-portal.local/storage/app/public/slide/Ssy6wiztc8Lp5dCuBrgC2GOoiuiFIO1UpOkzQ94R.png (404 response from image) and here is the actual image path  storage\app\public\slide\Ssy6wiztc8Lp5dCuBrgC2GOoiuiFIO1UpOkzQ94R.png

Comment: try changing to `storage\slide\Ssy6wiztc8Lp5dCuBrgC2GOoiuiFIO1UpOkzQ94R.png`

Comment: ✌️ glad it worked